# An Entire function with $g(1 − z) = 1 − g(z)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that an entire holomorphic function $g(z)$ satisfies the equation $g(1 − z) = 1 − g(z)$ for all $z ∈ \mathbb{C}$. Show that $g(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}$.

I was told to use the fact that $g(1/2) = 1/2$, but I'm not sure how this will lead to any contradiction. I know it should probably involve Picard's theorem

Comment: $g(z) = 1/2$ satisfies the equation, and $g(\mathbb C) \ne \mathbb C$..  Perhaps you want to assume $g$ is not constant?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** By Picard theorem you ether have $g(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$ or $g(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C} \backslash \{ a \}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now, if it is the second case and  $a \neq 1-a$ then $g(z)=1-a$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and hence $g(1-z)=a$.

From here it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Set
$$
h(z)=g\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Then, the property $g(1-z)=1-g(z)$ implies that
$$
h\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}=1-\left(h\left(-z+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
for all $z$ or
$$
h(-w)=-h(w),
$$
for all $w$. Hence, $h$ is odd and entire. Either $h\equiv 0$ or $h$ is onto, since, if the range of $h$ misses $a\ne 0$, then it also misses $-a$, which violates Little Picard's Theorem.